# npm not always using custom registry

Tags: npm

I have a CI build that downloads NPM and runs a build. We have a nexus installation that we use for maven builds, so I'd like to use this for caching NPM modules too.

I put this in a file called .npmrc in the build user's home directory:

```
registry=http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npmjs/
```

The grunt build starts using the custom registry, but then sometimes uses the official registry. Is there a way to force NPM to always use my custom registry? Here's a snippet of a build output:

```
[INFO] npm http GET http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npmjs/dateformat/-/dateformat-1.0.2-1.2.3.tgz
[INFO] npm http 200 http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npmjs/dateformat/-/dateformat-1.0.2-1.2.3.tgz
[INFO] npm http GET http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npmjs/ansi-regex
[INFO] npm http 200 http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npmjs/ansi-regex
[INFO] npm http GET http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npmjs/wrench
[INFO] npm http 200 http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npmjs/wrench
[INFO] npm http GET http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npmjs/inherits
[INFO] npm http GET http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npmjs/graceful-fs
[INFO] npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/semver/-/semver-4.3.6.tgz
[INFO] npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/-/uglify-js-2.4.23.tgz
[INFO] npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/closure-compiler/-/closure-compiler-0.2.6.tgz
[INFO] npm http GET http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npmjs/lodash-compat/3.10.1
[INFO] npm http 200 http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npmjs/inherits
[INFO] npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob/-/glob-5.0.12.tgz
[INFO] npm http 200 http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npmjs/graceful-fs
[INFO] npm http 200 http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npmjs/lodash-compat/3.10.1
```

Comment: Could there be a `.npmrc` in the project directory? Project configs override user configs.

Comment: Can a dependency override the global setting?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [npm-proxy-cache](https://github.com/runk/npm-proxy-cache) and it's works as a **local proxy**, seems like what you want.

Or, if you want a **local registry**, you can try [verdaccio](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio), and it's awesome.